# IBM ODM : How to define rule to validate only numeric values in a String

Tags: ibm-odm

I am totally new to IBM ODM and I have been given a set of rules to be designed in the IBM ODM rule designer. 
Simple If else and conditional rules I managed to write but I am struck how to write regular expression related rules in the IBM ODM. Can someone please help. 
I have Member variable of my XOM class which is  a String and I need to validate if it contains only Numbers and having 8 characters as length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a long-time user of ODM/JRules, it's my opinion that this is not a high-value use of business rules and that in the long run these rules will not be worthwhile.

Having said that, it should be easy enough to write a couple BOM or XOM methods to do what you want.

boolean containsOnlyNumbers(String string) {}
Verbalization: "{0} contains only numbers"

int length(String string, int length) {}
Verbalization: "{0} is {1} characters long"

Define these methods as static, on any class you want, perhaps a Utility class created just for them. Fill in the body of the methods with Java code to do the obvious things. Then verbalize them so your rule reads nicely:

If X contains only numbers and X is 8 characters long then

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Will follow your suggestion.

Comment: can we verbalize a method returning Boolean in similar way? For example I have a function that returns if Date is valid or not but in verbalization instead of including like "Date is not valid is true" how to write a verbalization that "Date is not valid" . SOmething like that. Are you able to understand my point?

Comment: The decision table editor wants the condition to have a placeholder (an parameter to be specified in the table). If your condition does not have an empty parameter, then the DT editor will provide the "is <a boolean>" for you, adding it to the condition you specified. So it will not behave as you are hoping. The idea is that the rule author should be in charge of the business policy -- it should not be buried in B2X or Java. So you should let the rule author provide the details of what makes a date valid.